# Render xhtml page by URL

Tags: jsf, url, mapping

how to render .xhtml pages by it's URL using JSF? It's something like using JSP and Servlet. Where you can map URL to every `doGet()` method and it will display page by it's name.
Thanx.

Comment: I have honestly no clue what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to map each xhtml to an url. That is done by JSF automatically when you set up your web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

You must place all your xhtml on your WEB-INF folder and you can access them with the URL:

```
http://localhost:port/WebAppContext/faces/page.xhtml
```